# Display user name and their city who have booked their tickets not by using HDFC bank for any of the bookings

Tags: sql, oracle

Display user name and their city who have booked their tickets not by using HDFC bank for any of the bookings. Sort the result based on the user name.

[This is the Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLQd0.jpg)
This is my code.

```
select distinct u.name,u.address
    from users u join bookingdetails b on b.user_id=u.user_id
    where lower(b.name) !='hdfc'
    order by u.name;
```

I am getting the expected output but passing only one of the test cases (can't see the test cases as it only showing pass or fail). I think this query can be written in a more effective way.

Data for the users table.

```
NAME                    USER_ID ADDRESS  
------------------- ---------- --------- 
Jaya                          6 Chennai  
Krena                         5 Mumbai   
Johan                         4 Delhi    
Ivan                          3 Chennai  
Tom                           2 Hyderabad
John                          1 Bangalore
```

Data for the bookingdetails table.

```
  BD_ID     ACC_NO  NAME          USER_ID    
  -------   ------ ----          ---------
   1001       1234 SBI                 1    
   1002       5623 KVB                 5    
   1003       9876 ICICI               4    
   1004       9193 HDFC                2    
   1005       8397 HDFC                3    
   1006       1234 SBI                 1
```

expected output:

```
 NAME                 ADDRESS
 ----------------     ----------
    Johan              Delhi
    John               Bangalore
    Krena              Mumbai
```

also, this is the output(given above) of your edited query and it is also passing only one test case.

Comment: Adding external links and images is a bad practice while asking a question. Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7998591) carefully. Not all will be able to connect to those external links or download images from them due to restrictions applied (from the local internet administrators at the workplace etc) . Even if they can, it will be hard to recreate the scenario from those images.

Comment: okay. I was not aware of the does and don't.

Comment: Great, you have now added the expected output in the text format. But, it is important to add sample data from both the tables (users and bookingdetails)  in the same way. Its more essential than the expected output because that's what lets us recreate the scenario and give you a working solution.

Comment: yes. I have edited. check the edits now!!

Comment: *"passing only one of the test cases (can't see the test cases as it only showing pass or fail)"* So the unit tests don't give you any indication of why the test failed? That's unspeakably poor practice. Also, impossible for us to tell you how to change your code to pass those tests if you can't tell us the criteria you need to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct u.name, u.address from users u
join bookingdetails b on b.user_id = u.user_id
where u.user_id not in 
( select user_id from bookingdetails where name='HDFC')
order by u.name;
```

This will hopefully pass both of your test cases.

Comment: I don't know what the test cases are..all because of that I am not able to find that what I am missing in my query. but apart from that this query is also passing only one test case.

Comment: @SakshiNegi: That's strange , because i've passed both of the tests successfully. Check the screen shots : https://imgur.com/a/EoLLIEN . If that too didn't worked for you, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need only the columns of one table (`users`), you may convert your query into `NOT EXISTS`

```
select u.name,u.address
    from users u where not exists 
    ( select 1 from bookingdetails b 
      where b.user_id=u.user_id
         and lower(b.name) ='hdfc'
    ) order by u.name;
```

Also, adding `lower()` may degrade the performance if the data volume is high and may not use an index if it exists on name. So, in a real time scenario( unlike the assignment which you are currently trying to complete), either store names in a single case( either lower or upper) or use a function based index on `lower(name)`.

**EDIT** : If you want to exclude the users which aren't present in the bookingdetails, you may use your original query or an exists condition.

```
select u.name,u.address
    from users u where exists 
    ( select 1 from bookingdetails b 
      where b.user_id=u.user_id
         and lower(b.name) != 'hdfc'
    ) order by u.name;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a30431e497b394ddb3023aa153168aeb)

Comment: After evaluating this query I am getting incorrect output. As there should not be the name of Jaya in the output table. for more details, you can check the table data. (given above ).

Comment: @SakshiNegi :  As far as I can see from that screenshot, user Jaya ( user_id 6 ) has no entry in HDFC bank, what do you expect to see?

Comment: we are expected to display the name and city of "Johan","john" and "krena".                 also from the above query written by me is showing the expected result and it is passing only one test case but not even showing that what the test cases are

Comment: KaushikNayak: I had already performed that query. And it was giving the incorrect output.

Comment: @SakshiNegi : An important thing which isn't stressed so far is that If you want us to provide a working solution, you should add the sample data and expected output as **text** format and not images. How could we recreate the SQLs using those images? How good would it be to you if we posted answers as screenshots? You are fortunate that your question is not downvoted yet because of adding images. So, if you expect us to provide solutions to you, add sample data in **tabular format**  as **plain text**  only.

Comment: @SakshiNegi : Well, my second query seems to give you the same output, check the demo link. I'm not sure what do you mean by  *"it is passing only one test case but not even showing that what the test cases are"*. In what context are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct u.name, u.address from users u join bookingdetails b 
on b.user_id = u.user_id
where u.user_id not in
(select user_id from bookingdetails where name = 'HDFC')
order by u.name;
```

This gives the correct answer as provided above and both test cases will sure be passed